# Subscript in Glade

Tags: application-development, python, quickly, glade

How can I format a text with subscript in Glade? I want to display a text with a formular such as H2O.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a Label switch on "*Use markup*" in the "*General*" tab of the Label properties.

Now you can use the [Pango Text Attribute Markup Language](http://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/PangoMarkupFormat.html) for formatting, for example

```
H<sub>2</sub>O
```

[image]